# How to combine gyroscope, acceleration of gravity, magnetometer to achieve the rotation of the picture?

Tags: android, gyroscope, hardware-acceleration, magnetometer

How to combine gyroscope, acceleration of gravity, magnetometer to achieve the rotation of the picture in android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the accelero-meter  alone for this,
These are the values for acceleration I receive:

***LandScape mode:***

Along X Axis : 8

Along Y axis : 0

***Potriat mode***

Along X Axis : 0

Along Y axis : 8

This data can help.